# comparing the date in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the date function.And I have to compare the  previous date with current data in iphone

For current date I have code:-

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

//Create the dateformatter object
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

//Set the required date format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

//Get the string date
NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

//Display on the console
NSLog(str);

//Set in the lable
[dateLabel setText:str];
```

But I want to implement the compare the current date & previous date in iphone

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this date formatting got to do with comparing dates?

Comment: I have  90 songs music application.I want to give 3 chance to user so he can listen any three song for current-date  after that he have to login for more song .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare dates using NSDate's comparison methods:

```
- (NSDate *)earlierDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate;
- (NSDate *)laterDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate;
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)other;

- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)otherDate;
```

Check [NSDate class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to know more..

Comment: thank you 
Can you explain me more on this or give me sample code for this

Comment: did you read the class reference? - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html 
If you open the instance methods section on the left, you can read details about each of these methods. If you have been able to use NSDateFormatter, i don't think you'll need more explanation on this.

Comment: I have 80 to 90 songs in one  application .I  want it should be control by current date & also I should give 3 chance to user for listening song .
This 3 song must available if he wants to listens again & again till the present day.But if he wants more song or(4th song ) to listens or listens this 3 song for tomorrow than .He will have login .Give me solution for this. thanks in advance

Comment: if its a different problem ask a different question. and i don't think any one on stack overflow is going to 'give you a solution' for something just like that, ask a question describing what are you trying to do, what have you done so far and where you are stuck... then people will respond..